# Deriving basic form of sine wave

Tags: waves

I'm trying to derive the basic form of a sine wave:

$$y = A\sin(wt + θ)$$

I'm guessing I could probably first derive the cosine wave as follows and then add a phase of $- π/2$.

$$y = Re(z) = Re(A\cos wt + i\sin wt) = A\cos wt $$

Is this derivation the most common method and if it isn't what are other ways could I use to derive the basic form of a sine wave? Any other info regarding this basic form would be greatly appreciated as well?

Comment: Might [math.se] be better suited for this question?

Comment: I was considering Mathematics, but as this is a practical application, I thought Physics might be more suitable. Shall I move it anyway?

Comment: How is this a practical application?

Comment: Simple harmonic wave function - https://www.physicskey.com/35/simple-harmonic-wave-function-and-wave-equation

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it the derivation of the function $\sin(\theta)$ of angle $\theta$ comes from the triangle. This is purely mathematical.

The equation that you quote 
$$y = A \sin(wt + \theta)$$

can be derived by solving the second order differential equation for simple harmonic motion

$$ {d^2x \over dt^2} = -{k\over m} x $$

here for a mass, $m$, on a spring with constant, $k$, - but as you noted changing the phase factor $\theta$ gives cosine and other waves....